# how to make CBC using DES in java?

Tags: java, security

Hey everyone i'm about make a program encrypt strings using DES algorithm i want to use CBC mode in this program so i have to make (IV) and XORed it with next Plain Text block

my question is, the (IV) data type is it Byte[] ? and is it enough to add it to the XORed value to the next block and encrypt it ?

this is my code

```
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;


import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class DESEncryption {

private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
public static final String DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DES";
private KeySpec myKeySpec;
private SecretKeyFactory mySecretKeyFactory;
private Cipher cipher;
byte[] keyAsBytes;
private String myEncryptionKey;
private String myEncryptionScheme;
SecretKey key;

public DESEncryption() throws Exception
{
    myEncryptionKey = "ThisIsSecretEncryptionKey";
    myEncryptionScheme = DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
    keyAsBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
    myKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyAsBytes);
    mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
    key = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);
}

/**
 * <span class="IL_AD" id="IL_AD2">Method</span> To Encrypt The String
 */
public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) {
    String encryptedString = null;
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        encryptedString = base64encoder.encode(encryptedText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encryptedString;
}
/**
 * Method To Decrypt An Ecrypted String
 */
public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
    String decryptedText=null;
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        BASE64Decoder base64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] encryptedText = base64decoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedString);
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
        decryptedText= bytes2String(plainText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decryptedText;
}
/**
 * Returns String From An Array Of Bytes
 */
private static String bytes2String(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        stringBuffer.append((char) bytes[i]);
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}

/**
 * Testing the DES Encryption And Decryption Technique
 */
public static void main(String args []) throws Exception
{
    DESEncryption myEncryptor= new DESEncryption();

    String stringToEncrypt="Sanjaal.com";
    String encrypted=myEncryptor.encrypt(stringToEncrypt);
    String decrypted=myEncryptor.decrypt(encrypted);

    System.out.println("String To Encrypt: "+stringToEncrypt);
    System.out.println("Encrypted Value : " + encrypted);
    System.out.println("Decrypted Value : "+decrypted);

}   

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this program? Is it a school assignment?

Comment: yeah it's and i wanna some idea is what i'm do is right ?

Comment: You're right that the IV will be a `byte[]` (which is not the same as `Byte[]`), but I'm not familiar enough with the process to say about the rest. In general, for real-world code, it's best to use existing tested libraries for this sort of thing.

Comment: googling for "DES CBC example in java" will return you plenty of examples. Learn to use google.

Comment: @JB Nizet i googled it but i don't want any built-in functions to implement the CBC mode :(